# Drupal permission for anonymous user

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-permissions

I have create module for uploading files into database, and only administrator can upload that files. So I have `hook_permission` for administer to upload files:

```
function upload_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer uploader' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer Uploader'),
      'description' => t('Allow the following roles to upload files files to the server.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Also I create several custom nodes with path `files/node/%` and now I need permission for anonymous users to see page with custom nodes. Below I add this permission:

```
'access files/node/%' => array(
      'title' => t('Access Files'),
      'description' => t('Access Files.'),
    ),
```

and still don't work. Is there any other solution how anonymous user can view the page with custom nodes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I know, just check the permission "view published content" in the CMS permission page that should be checked for the anonymous user role. For viewing a Drupal node no specific permission needed until you are using any individual node permission settings. Also, for your custom node path please use the below settings array in your hook_menu to make all path works with the URL 'files/node/%'.

```
/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
function yourmodule_menu() {
    $items = array();    
    $items['files/node/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'Files node',
        'page callback' => '_yourmodule_page_callback',
        'page arguments' => array(2),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      );
    return $items;
}
```

Just notice the below line of code, this say that anyone with the permission 'access content' (View published content) can see these node.

```
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
```

Hope this will help you!